# I2C PROGRAMMING ON ARM

Tags: microcontroller, accelerometer, i2c, mpu6050

I'm unable to use I2C on an ARM CORTEX M3 process.
What am I doing wrong? Which test could I perform to find the problem?

It is a GD32F130C8 (master) and I'm programming it with KEIL (using the GD32F1x0 Firmware Library)

The slave is a MPU-6050 (accelorometer)

I defined the variable with local address and MPU-6050 device:

```
      #define I2C_ACCELEROMETER_ADDRESS 0xD0 //( 0x68 + one bit)
      #define I2C_OWN_ADDRESS 0x72
```

Then I initialized the I2C PIN this way:

```
    //Init I2C communication to accelerometer
    // enable I2C0 clock 
    rcu_periph_clock_enable(RCU_I2C0);
    // connect PB8 to I2C0_SCL 
    gpio_af_set(GPIOB, GPIO_AF_1, GPIO_PIN_8);
    // connect PB9 to I2C0_SDA 
    gpio_af_set(GPIOB, GPIO_AF_1, GPIO_PIN_9);
    gpio_mode_set(GPIOB, GPIO_MODE_AF, GPIO_PUPD_PULLUP,GPIO_PIN_8);
    gpio_output_options_set(GPIOB, GPIO_OTYPE_OD, GPIO_OSPEED_50MHZ,GPIO_PIN_8);
    gpio_mode_set(GPIOB, GPIO_MODE_AF, GPIO_PUPD_PULLUP,GPIO_PIN_9);
    gpio_output_options_set(GPIOB, GPIO_OTYPE_OD, GPIO_OSPEED_50MHZ,GPIO_PIN_9);
```

Then I initialized the I2C this way:

```
    void I2C_Accelerometer_init(void){
        // configure I2C0 clock 
        i2c_clock_config(I2C0, 100000, I2C_DTCY_2);
        // configure I2C0 address 
        i2c_mode_addr_config(I2C0, I2C_I2CMODE_ENABLE, I2C_ADDFORMAT_7BITS, I2C_OWN_ADDRESS);
        // enable I2C0
        i2c_enable(I2C0);
        // enable acknowledge 
        i2c_ack_config(I2C0, I2C_ACK_ENABLE);
    }
```

Then periodically (each second) I try to get the data from the accelerometer.
There is no error but the variable "accelerometer_x_high" is always zero (this is basically my problem).

The following code is executed each second. As you can see I set power management to 0, then I request register with accelerometer data, then I try to get the data from the slave device:

```
    extern uint8_t Accelerometer_X_High;

    //periodically called by timers in it.c
    void GetAccelerometerData(void){
        uint8_t bytesToReadIndex=0;

        //WAKE UP ACCELEROMETER (6B 00)

        // wait until I2C bus is idle
      while(i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_I2CBSY));
      // send a start condition to I2C bus 
      i2c_start_on_bus(I2C0);

        // wait until SBSEND bit is set
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_SBSEND));

        // send slave address to I2C bus
      i2c_master_addressing(I2C0, I2C_ACCELEROMETER_ADDRESS, I2C_TRANSMITTER);

        // wait until ADDSEND bit is set
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_ADDSEND));

      // clear ADDSEND bit 
      i2c_flag_clear(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_ADDSEND);

    // send a data byte 
      i2c_data_transmit(I2C0,0x6B);  //PWR MANAGEMENT
      // wait until the transmission data register is empty
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_TBE));
        // send a data byte 
      i2c_data_transmit(I2C0,0x00);  //WAKE UP
        // wait until the transmission data register is empty
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_TBE));

    // send a stop condition to I2C bus
      i2c_stop_on_bus(I2C0);


      while(I2C_CTL0(I2C0)&0x0200);


        //REQUEST ACELEROMETER DATA (3B )

        // wait until I2C bus is idle
      while(i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_I2CBSY));
      // send a start condition to I2C bus 
      i2c_start_on_bus(I2C0);

        // wait until SBSEND bit is set
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_SBSEND));

        // send slave address to I2C bus
      i2c_master_addressing(I2C0, I2C_ACCELEROMETER_ADDRESS, I2C_TRANSMITTER);

        // wait until ADDSEND bit is set
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_ADDSEND));
      // clear ADDSEND bit 
      i2c_flag_clear(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_ADDSEND);

    // send a data byte 
      i2c_data_transmit(I2C0,0x3B);  //ACCELEROMETER REGISTER
      // wait until the transmission data register is empty
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_TBE));


    // send a stop condition to I2C bus
      i2c_stop_on_bus(I2C0);


      while(I2C_CTL0(I2C0)&0x0200);




        //now reopen the bus to receive the reply



        // wait until I2C bus is idle
      while(i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_I2CBSY));
      // send a start condition to I2C bus
      i2c_start_on_bus(I2C0);
      // wait until SBSEND bit is set 
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_SBSEND));
      // send slave address to I2C bus 
      i2c_master_addressing(I2C0, I2C_ACCELEROMETER_ADDRESS, I2C_RECEIVER);
        // wait until ADDSEND bit is set 
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_ADDSEND));

        // if we receive only one byte: reset ACKEN bit
      i2c_ack_config(I2C0, I2C_ACK_DISABLE);

      //clear ADDSEND bit 
      i2c_flag_clear(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_ADDSEND);

      // if we receive only one byte: send stop condition
      i2c_stop_on_bus(I2C0);


      /* wait until the RBNE bit is set */
      while(!i2c_flag_get(I2C0, I2C_FLAG_RBNE));
      //read a data from I2C_DATA 
      Accelerometer_X_High = i2c_data_receive(I2C0);

      // if we receive more bytes: send a stop condition to I2C bus 
      //i2c_stop_on_bus(I2C0);
      while(I2C_CTL0(I2C0)&0x0200);
      // enable acknowledge 
      i2c_ack_config(I2C0, I2C_ACK_ENABLE);

    }
```

acquiring signals with oscilloscope I get the following result:
[image: communication decoded]

this is a screenshot with entire signal:
http://www.tr3ma.com/Dati/IMG_1526.JPG

On the signal there are also strange spikes:

http://www.tr3ma.com/Dati/spike1.JPG

http://www.tr3ma.com/Dati/spike2.JPG

http://www.tr3ma.com/Dati/spike3.JPG

http://www.tr3ma.com/Dati/spike4.JPG

Comment: Writing questions in all-caps is eternally considered rude.  Please fix.

Comment: Can you read any other device register (aka sub address) successfully, such as a "who am I" or device ID register?

Answer (score 0):

It works. I created a loop to read all the registers and I was able to read the entire content of the chip. There is no error on the firmware. The only problem is that the chip is not the one that I supposed it to be. I have to find the right part number of accelerometer and find the register to wake it up.